# TypeError: subcategory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cslug'

Tags: python, html, django

I have a URL path like this: [www.example.com/caetegory/mens/mens-shoes](http://www.example.com/caetegory/mens/mens-shoes)

As you can see, the URL path includes 3 slugs in this example.

I have 3 different class for these categories. And slug is included inside each of them separately. What do I need to do in order to be able to render the product accordingly to the subcategory
Every single help or thought is highly appreciated. I can't find any source for that.

URLS.py

models.py

```
Class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='media/category', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('product_by_category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name 


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    subcat_name =models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subcat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='media/subcategory', blank=True)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcat_name


class SubSubCategory(models.Model):
    subcat_name = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    subsubcat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subsubcat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/subsubcategory', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'subsubcategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'subsubcategories'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subsubcat_name

class Products(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=3)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to ='media/products', blank=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubSubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='abc')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

```
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:cat_slug>', views.category, name='category'),
    path('<slug:cslug>/<slug:sslug>', views.subcategory, name='subcat'),
   
]
```

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from category import models
from products.models import Products
from .models import SubCategory, Category, SubSubCategory



def category(request, cat_slug):
    product = Products.objects.filter(subcategory__cat_name__slug=cat_slug)
    count = product.count()
    
    return render(request, 'myproject/store.html', {
        'product':product ,
        'count':count,
    })


def subcategory(request, sslug):
    product = Products.objects.filter(subcategory__slug=sslug)
    count = product.count()


    return render(request, 'myproject/store2.html', {'product':product, 'count':count})
```

```
contextproessor.py
from .models import Category, SubCategory, SubSubCategory
from .models import Category

def category_links(request):
    subcategory = SubCategory.objects.all()
    subsubcategory = SubSubCategory.objects.all()
    category =  Category.objects.all()
    
    return dict(category=category, subcategory=subcategory, subsubcategory=subsubcategory)
```

Inside html file
.html

````
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {% for c in category %}
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' c.slug %}"> {{c.cat_name}} </a>
                                 <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                                     {% for s in subcategory %}
                                      {% if s.cat_name.slug == c.slug %}   
                                      <!--or s.catname_id == c.id  -->
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'subcat' cslug=s.cat_name.slug sslug=s.slug %}"> {{s.subcat_name}} </a>
                                    <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                                            
                                        {% for ss in subsubcategory %}
                                        {% if ss.subcat_name_id == s.id%}
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> {{ss.subsubcat_name}}</a></li>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}

                                    </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                              {% endfor%}
                            </ul>
            ```
it worked of the category view but it doesnot worked for the subcategory view while using passing two slug in the url
````

Answer (score 0):

Your url path must match the view, so in this url:

```py
path('<slug:cslug>/<slug:sslug>', views.subcategory, name='subcat'),
```

expects two slugs, so the corresponding view needs to accept two slugs:

```py
def subcategory(request, cslug, sslug):
   # rest of your code here
```

This way the `subcategory` view will be able to receive both the `cslug`, and the `sslug` as parameters.  You can expand this to as many parameters as you want.